# How can I parametrize my fixture and get testdata to parametreize my tests

Tags: pytest

I'm a starter with pytest. Just learned about fixture and tried to do this:

My tests call functions I wrote, and get test data from a code practicing website.
Each test is from a particular page and has several sets of test data.
So, I want to use @pytest.mark.parametrize to parametrize my single test func.
Also, as the operations of the tests are samelike, I want to made the pageObject instantiation and the steps to get test data from page as a fixture.

```
# content of conftest.py

@pytest.fixture
def get_testdata_from_problem_page():
    def _get_testdata_from_problem_page(problem_name):
        page = problem_page.ProblemPage(problem_name)
        return page.get_sample_data()
    return _get_testdata_from_problem_page

# content of test_problem_a.py
import pytest
from page_objects import problem_page
from problem_func import problem_a

@pytest.mark.parametrize('input,expected', test_data)
def test_problem_a(get_testdata_from_problem_page):
    input, expected = get_testdata_from_problem_page("problem_a")
    assert problem_a.problem_a(input) == expected
```

Then I realized, as above, I can't parametrize the test using pytest.mark as the test_data should be given outside the test function....

Are there solutions for this?  Thanks very much~~

Comment: It is not clear what the fixture shall do - currently it just defines a function and does nothing. I'm also not sure what your test shall do - shall it run the tests for one specific problem, or shall it iterate over all problems? What is the sample data you get back - is it just a tuple of input, expected or is it an array of different tests? We need a bit more information here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. the fixture return the test data I got from page using selenium,which is like https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-a-string/problem. It is a list with 1-3 
 items of sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to write one parameterized test per page. In this case you just have to write a function instead of a fixture and use that for parametrization:

```py
import pytest
from page_objects import problem_page
from problem_func import problem_a

def get_testdata_from_problem_page(problem_name):
    page = problem_page.ProblemPage(problem_name)
    # returns a list of (input, expected) tuples
    return page.get_sample_data()

@pytest.mark.parametrize('input,expected', 
    get_testdata_from_problem_page("problem_a")) 
def test_problem_a(input, expected):
    assert problem_a.problem_a(input) == expected
```

As you wrote, a fixture can only be used as a parameter to a test function or to another fixture, not in a decorator.

If you want to use the function to get test data elsewhere, just move it to a common module and import it. This can be just some custom utility module, or you could put it into `contest.py`, though you still have to import it.

Note also that the fixture you wrote does not do anything - it defines a local function that is not called and returns.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot..but i also want the get_testdata_from_problem_page(name) as a setup for other test... that's why I tried to use it as a fixture...what should i do...

Comment: I added a note to the answer.